# How can I do Database testing with Selenium RC?

Tags: selenium-rc

How do i start database testing with selenium and SQL SERVER, kinldy let me know which all jar's do i have to download and start .

Thanks, 
PK

Answer (score 0):

Selenium RC is meant to test html pages, using javascript, which is wrapped into client drivers for several languages. If you need anything from database it doesn't relate to selenium, just include your DB client libs and access it independently to Selenium.

Comment: Thanks Roman, I understood what you are trying to tell but i have a question ..HOW??

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is used mostly for web application testing. 
You can use java features for database testing.

See the example given in the link below. You can use sql queries in java program to fetch results from database and validate them in the java program itself.

[click here](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/execute-sql-query.shtml)